# Как поместить эти кнопки на один уровень?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

**Мне нужно чтобы эти кнопки были на одном уровне с кнопкой 1 и были помещены как (1 2 3 4 5). Как мне это сделать?**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AverageCounter.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="DarkSlateBlue" Padding="8" CornerRadius="10" Margin="15,5,15,0">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Frame_Tapped"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label Text="Average Counter" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        
        <Label
            x:Name="label_average"
            Text="Средний балл: "
            TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="24"
            Padding="25,15,0,0" />
        <Label
            x:Name="label_marks"
            Text="Оценки: "
            TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="20"
            Padding="25,5,0,0" />
        <Button
            x:Name="button1"
            Clicked="button1_Clicked"
            Text="1" FontSize="16"
            BorderColor="#7D0606"
            BorderWidth="3"
            CornerRadius="16"
            Margin="157,0,157,0"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            BackgroundColor="White" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="button5">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#7D0606"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        <Button
            x:Name="button2"
            Clicked="button2_Clicked"
            Text="2"
            FontSize="16"
            BorderColor="#f53d50"
            BorderWidth="3"
            CornerRadius="16"
            Margin="157,0,157,0"
            BackgroundColor="White" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="button5">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f53d50"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        <Button
            x:Name="button3"
            Clicked="button3_Clicked"
            Text="3"
            FontSize="16"
            BorderColor="#ffb700"
            BorderWidth="3"
            CornerRadius="16"
            Margin="157,0,157,0"
            BackgroundColor="White" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="button5">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ffb700"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        <Button
            x:Name="button4"
            Clicked="button4_Clicked"
            Text="4"
            FontSize="16"
            BorderColor="#88ebc3"
            BorderWidth="3"
            CornerRadius="16"
            Margin="157,0,157,0"
            BackgroundColor="White" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="button5">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#88ebc3"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        <Button
            x:Name="button5"
            Clicked="button5_Clicked"
            Text="5"
            FontSize="16"
            BorderColor="#c781d4"
            BorderWidth="3"
            CornerRadius="16"
            Margin="157,0,157,0"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="White" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="button5">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#c781d4"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        <Button
            Clicked="button_clear_Clicked"
            Text="Очистить"
            FontSize="16"
            BorderColor="#000000"
            BorderWidth="3"
            CornerRadius="16"
            Margin="100,0,100,0"
            BackgroundColor="White" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="button5">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: И вообще стараться разделять на блоки ваш контент. Так проще работать с элементами.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato я просто только вчера начал пытаться изучать xamarin да и вообще xaml в общем поэтому я многого могу не знать

Comment: Измените свой макет StackLayout на FlexLayout или Grid макеты, тк StackLayout - позиционирует элементы по горизонтали или вертикали - по умолчанию - это вертикальное положение элементов. Это все беру из документации. Ссылки ниже дал. удачи в обучении

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts - тут все очень популярно объясняется :)

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato спасибо огромное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовать другой макет мб?

**[StackLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout)**

**[RelativeLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout)**

**[AbsoluteLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout)**

**[Grid](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid)**

**[FlexLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout)**